# How to decompose a 3x3 matrix into two identical vectors

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix, say:

```
mat = ([1, 0.63, 0.45],
  [0.63, 1, 0.35],
  [0.45, 0.35, 1])
```

And I need to decompose it into LL'

I know for a fact that L is:

```
[0.9, 0.7, 0.5]
```

But what is the python code for decomposing a square matrix in this way?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `LL'` does not equal `mat`; diagonal elements are off.